# How to remove a column with data?

Tags: sql

Is it possible to remove a column from table which have data?

Comment: yes it is possible. Which database?

Comment: If it has primary foreign key relationships then you must need to delete the constraints, indexes(if present) and then it allows you to drop column

Answer (score 1):

The SQL syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP COLUMN column_name;
```

It should work for any database.

Answer (score 0):

You must think about: What happens to the data?

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN ColumnName;
```

Check this (SQL-Server Syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE #test(Col1 INT,Col2 INT);
INSERT INTO #test VALUES(1,10),(2,20),(3,30);

SELECT * FROM #test;

ALTER TABLE #test DROP COLUMN Col1;

SELECT * FROM #test;

DROP TABLE #test;
```